# Getting issue with passing string variable in JSON request

Tags: karate

I am stuck in a scenario where i have created customized java code which returns a string. Next, I am passing it in another \path with JSON request below:

```
Given url 'url'
def browserCall = Java.type('package.browserCall')
 * def parameter = browserCall.method(data)// returns a string 
 Given path 'path'
* request 
 """
 { 
 "data1":"string",
 "data2":"string",
 "data3":"string",
 "data4":"3",
 "data5":"#(responseParameter)",
 "data6":"{\"data7\":\"string\",\"data8\": \"+parameter+\"}",
 "data9":"string"
 }
 """
 When method post
 Then status 200
```

When i hit it I get invalid JSON data object. I tried passing parameter as '#(parameter)' under data6 but did not get luck. tried to convert parameter to json and then passed it through data 6 but still did not get luck.
I am not getting any lead. Please help.

Comment: I haven't used Karate, but the [readme.md](https://github.com/intuit/karate) states "It is worth pointing out that JSON is a 'first class citizen' of the syntax such that you can express payload and expected data without having to use double-quotes and without having to enclose JSON field names in quotes. There is no need to 'escape' characters like you would have had to in Java or other programming languages."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read the “type conversion” section of the doc carefully: https://github.com/intuit/karate#type-conversion